# How to Install and Run multiple MySQL Servers versions on centos?

Tags: centos, mysql5.5, mysql5.1

I am new to MySQL database and I would like to install and run multiple MySQL server versions in CentOS server.

I have done following things  but no luck.

1. Installed mysql 5.1.86 with default settings.
2. Trying to install another MySQL server version 5.5.30 with help of following links:
   http://www.colestock.com/blogs/2008/02/installing-multiple-versions-of-mysql.html
   http://bobcares.com/blog/?p=91

however I was unable to install the another MySQL server (5.5.30). And facing lot of issues as follows:

1. Second MySQL (5.5.30) is checking for old MySQL server configuration files and getting conflict.
2. Suddenly, my old MySQL server (5.1.86) has stopped automatically. Not started till I removed the new server files completely and reboot my machine.

Comment: No - the forum is for help with specuific problems. Not to provide tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this with the CentOS package manager - as you've discovered it is designed to protect you from yourself and keep you from doing things you almost certainly should not do on a production system.

The solution is to compile and install MySQL manually, to different locations, and to configure each instance to listen on a different IP address (or port).
If you're feeling ambitious (or need to do this to several machines) you can roll your own packages based on those installations.

Compilation and installation of software is left as an exercise for the reader -- you should be able to handle this using the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/) for the relevant versions.